# Choosing a column db

Tags: database, nosql

I am trying to evaluate and use column db for my application.

I have evaluated [InfiniDb](http://www.infinidb.org/) and [InfoBright](http://www.infobright.com/). Can you suggest some other Column DB's

Comment: Apache cassandra!!, you have any specific requirements?

Comment: @zengr like I would like to run OLAP on the column db, or run OLAP like queries on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question might suggest that column-store database are NoSQL database.

Those are two different kind of database / way of representing datas that should not be confused.

I do personally use [LucidDB](http://www.luciddb.org/) that works like a charm. I use it for Business Intelligence use, and LucidDB is optimized for Business Intelligence. One of the activest member of the community [Nicholas Goodman](http://www.nicholasgoodman.com/bt/blog/) , someone really influent in the world of Open Source BI.

For this use, it is really well though and I would recommend it for this use.

Answer (score 0):

There's a good list on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Column-oriented_DBMS#Implementations)